# Как правильно написать игру - угадай число

Tags: javascript, html

1. Программа "загадывает" случайное число от 1 до 7
2. Игроку предлагается вводить числа. Программа должна запоминать, сколько
   попыток было у игрока. Должны запоминаться попытки, содержащие только
   числа,в заданном промежутке от 1 до 7.
3. Если игрок нажмет "Отмена" игра должна завершиться.
4. Если игрок сделал три попытки и не угадал число, игра должна завершиться.
5. Все сообщения выводятся с помощью **alert** и **prompt**.
6. **Обязательное условие** при написании игры:

   ● Необходимо использовать continue и break в бесконечном цикле для решения
   этой задачи.

Comment: Ммм... Классическое учебное задание! А причины закрыть и нету :(

Comment: @Leks как мне кажется, не выполненно условие *При этом, не должны учитываться попытки, содержащие не числа, а также числа, не попадающие в заданный промежуток (от 1 до 7).*

Comment: @Leks а что за интересное условие `con == 'string'`?

Comment: И еще, мне кажется, что число должно один раз загадываться, а не в каждой итерации цикла. ДА еще и функция заново создается каждый раз...

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101072/discussion-between-stepan-kasyanenko-and-leks).

Answer (score 2):

```js
  function randomInteger(min, max) {
      let rand = min + Math.random() * (max + 1 - min);
      return Math.floor(rand); 
    };
  let number = randomInteger(1, 7)


function ygaday(){
  let i = 1;
  let d = [];
 while(true){
     
     let con = +prompt('Угадайте число от 1 до 7', '');

    if( i >= 3 ){
    console.log( `${con} и ${number}` )
    d.push(con);
    alert(' 3 попытки закончились ...');
    console.log( `Вы вели числа ${ d } правильное число ${number}` );
    break
    };
   
  if( con == null || con == ''){
      break 
    } else if( number == con ){
      alert( `Вы угадали правильное число ${number}` )
      break
    } else if( con == new Number(con) && con <= 7){
        d.push(con);
       ++i
      console.log( `${con} и ${number}` )
    } 
  } 
 
};

ygaday();
```

Comment: я бы придрался к `new Number`, созданию функции в цикле, еще `while(true)` так себе практика, однако это есть в условии, отступы ну и - сложно очень, много кода

Comment: Опять у вас осталась волшебная (нет) проверка на строку `con == 'string'` - это сравнение не имеет смысла в данном коде, оно всегда будет `false`.

Comment: Косяк - да. Ну а в целом еще есть несколько незначительных замечаний. Например, переменная `d` - не очень правильно хранить так числа введенные. Лучшие бы массив)

Comment: @Leks к сожалению, четких критериев никто не даст. Да их наверное и не существует. Только опыт и вопрос удобства\читаемости\производительности.

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko все замечания устранил ...